# 403 Forbidden when using csrf angularjs

Tags: angularjs, express, csrf

I use [csurf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) library in my project but it doesn't work. This is my code:

server.js

```
var express      = require('express');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var csrf         = require('csurf');
var line         = require('./server/line');

app.use(cookieParser());
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true})

app.use(csrfProtection, function(req, res) {
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.code !== 'EBADCSRFTOKEN') return next(err) 

    res.status(403)
    res.send('form tampered with')
})

app.post('/getAccessTokenLINE', line.getAccessToken);
```

auth.js (I add '_csrf' into both header and body)

```
angular.module('auth', ['openline', 'ngCookies'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        //my config
    })
    .factory('Auth', function ($http, $window, $rootScope, $cookies) {
        return {
            getAccessTokenLINE: function() {
                return $http.post($rootScope.server.url + '/getAccessTokenLINE', {
                    channelId     : $window.sessionStorage.lineChannelId,
                    channelSecret : $window.sessionStorage.lineChannelSecret,
                    callbackURL   : $window.sessionStorage.callbackURL,
                    getTokenURL   : $window.sessionStorage.lineGetTokenURL,
                    code          : $window.sessionStorage.authorizationCode,
                    _csrf         : $cookies._csrf
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        _csrf         : $cookies._csrf
                    }
                });
        }
}
```

line.js (The 403 Forbidden error occurred when I send request to my API (/getAccessTokenLINE) , so I think this file is not important)

```
var request = require('request');

function getAccessToken(req, res, next) {
    var channelId         = req.body.channelId;
    var channelSecret     = req.body.channelSecret;
    var callbackURL       = req.body.callbackURL;
    var getTokenURL       = req.body.getTokenURL;
    var authorizationCode = req.body.code;

    request.post({
        uri: getTokenURL,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        form: {
            grant_type    : 'authorization_code',
            client_id     : channelId,
            client_secret : channelSecret,
            redirect_uri  : callbackURL,
            code          : authorizationCode
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            return res.send(body);
        } else {
            return res.send(response.statusCode, error);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to change

```
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true})
```

to

```
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true, ignoreMethods: ['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS']})
```

then I can access my API as normal. So, I think there is nothing wrong about setting.

I don't understand what went wrong.

EDIT: I found the solution.

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrf());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
    return next();
});
```

Comment: where did you declare `line.getAccessToken` in server.js

Comment: @Burdy Sorry, I edited

Answer (score 0):

In Express code

 `res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());`

So your csrf cookie will have key 'XSRF-TOKEN'. You can't get cookies from _csrf key

`_csrf: $cookies._csrf`

Comment: I checked the cookie in my Request headers: 
Cookie:_csrf=emRIOclyiO6SH73Ur7yZhojT.

And I'm sure I can get that value because I have tested by console.log($cookies._csrf);

Comment: app.use(csrfProtection, function(req, res) {
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
});  you forgot the next()

Comment: Nothing different

Comment: after add next(), recheck your $cookie in angular.

Answer (score 0):

If you using angularjs, you just need to add `csrf` code on the server side. For example:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var csrf = require('csurf')
var express = require('express')

var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.code !== 'EBADCSRFTOKEN') return next(err)

  // handle CSRF token errors here
  res.status(403)
  res.send('Error messages')
})
```

And angularjs will do the rest by itself ([reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) - go to **Security Considerations** section)

> Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Protection
>
> XSRF is an attack technique by which the attacker can trick an authenticated user into unknowingly executing actions on your website. AngularJS provides a mechanism to counter XSRF. When performing XHR requests, the $http service reads a token from a cookie (by default, XSRF-TOKEN) and sets it as an HTTP header (X-XSRF-TOKEN). Since only JavaScript that runs on your domain could read the cookie, your server can be assured that the XHR came from JavaScript running on your domain. The header will not be set for cross-domain requests.